# Tidy HTML with BaseX

Tags: java, browser-automation, xpath, validation, xml-file

How do I tidy this `HTML` for `baseX`?  Working from a [basic](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-examples/src/main/java/org/basex/examples/create/HTMLExample.java) example.

Looks like the `HTML` isn't valid, or at least `baseX` has apparent problems with parsing it:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldBaseX$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldBaseX$ gradle clean run

> Task :run FAILED
Jan 01, 2019 8:11:21 PM org.basex.examples.local.ScraperForHTML fetch
INFO: name  Resources  Size  Input Path  
---------------------------------

0 Databases.

Exception in thread "main" org.basex.core.BaseXException: "http://books.toscrape.com/" (Line 665): </a> found, </img> expected.
        at org.basex.core.Command.execute(Command.java:78)
        at org.basex.core.Command.execute(Command.java:90)
        at org.basex.examples.local.ScraperForHTML.fetch(ScraperForHTML.java:38)
        at org.basex.examples.local.App.helloWorld(App.java:24)
        at org.basex.examples.local.App.main(App.java:14)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorldBaseX$
```

code:

```
package org.basex.examples.local;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.basex.core.BaseXException;
import org.basex.core.Context;
import org.basex.core.Databases;
import org.basex.core.cmd.CreateDB;
import org.basex.core.cmd.List;
import org.basex.core.cmd.Set;
import org.basex.util.list.StringList;

public class ScraperForHTML implements Scraper{

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
    private Properties properties = new Properties();

    private ScraperForHTML() {
    }

    public ScraperForHTML(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
        LOG.fine(properties.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void fetch() throws BaseXException, MalformedURLException   {
        URL url = new URL(properties.getProperty("htmlURL"));
        String databaseName = properties.getProperty("databaseName");

        Context context = new Context();
        LOG.info(new List().execute(context));

        new Set("parser", "html").execute(context);
        new CreateDB(databaseName, url.toString()).execute(context);


        Databases databases = context.databases();
        StringList stringListOfDatabases = databases.listDBs();
        String currentDatabaseName = null;

        Iterator<String> databaseIterator = stringListOfDatabases.iterator();

        while (databaseIterator.hasNext()) {
            currentDatabaseName=databaseIterator.next();
            LOG.info(currentDatabaseName);
            //not quite sure how to query a database...
        }


      //  new DropDB(databaseName).execute(context);
        context.close();
    }


}
```

Notably, this `XQuery` seems to [work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53991205/262852) fine:

```
thufir@dur:~/basex$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex$ cat html_fetch_parse.xq 


fetch:xml("http://books.toscrape.com/", map {
  'parser': 'html',
  'htmlparser': map { 'html': false(), 'nodefaults': true() }
})

thufir@dur:~/basex$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing TagSoup in your classpath. As it is stated [here](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Parsers#HTML_Parser) you should have one to be able to successfully import html format. Since html is often not a well-formed XML, it should be pre-processed before importing.

When one does not have TagSoup the input format is considered as XML and has to be well-formed. Your example is missing closing `</img>` tag which makes importing without TagSoup not possible.

Comment: 'BaseX` should come with `TagSoup`, should it not?